# Load file content , create script from content and detect script load

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, load, es6-promise

How to avoid use of setTimeout .
For now setTimeout is my only solution.

Important : i dont load pure JS file , i load file with html and js.

LOADED FILE :

```
 <div>HTML part</div>
 <script>
   // js part
 </script>
```

`this s.addEventListener('load', () => {}) not fired!`

```
    loadVanilla: async function(arg, parent, callback) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch(arg, {}).then(res => {return res.text()}).then(html => {
                let t = html.split('<script defer>')[1];
                let hc = html.split('<script defer>')[0];
                let sc = t.split('</script>')[0];
                let s = document.createElement('script');
                s.innerHTML = sc;
                if(typeof parent === 'undefined') {
                    document.body.innerHTML += hc;
                } else {
                    parent.innerHTML += hc;
                }
                document.body.appendChild(s);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('S LOADED')
                    resolve(`loaded good ${arg} \n `)
                    if(callback) callback()
                }, 10)
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject('bad')
            })
        })
    },
```

For some reasons onload or DOMContentLoaded not works:

```
    s.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        console.log('S LOADED')
        resolve(`loaded good ${arg} \n `)
        if(callback) callback()
    })
```

Comment: Don't use `async function () { return new Promise`. It's not advisable

Comment: I guess the event you are looking for is called 'load'
`s.addEventListener('load', () => {});`

Comment: @evolutionxbox sometimes using an async iife is more messy. could you point me how do it your way in my answer?

Comment: You can remove the async keyword since the function returns a promise

Answer (score 0):

`<script>` has a `load` event which you can use. Also it has an `error` event which you should use to reject the promise.

Also you should check whether the server responses without HTTP error.

Also you should never do `innerHTML +=` ! This overwrites any DOM bindings and leads to bugs! Use `HTMLElement::insertAdjacentHTML()` and a polyfill if you need to target the older browsers.

Also I would recommend add `null` as default values for the optional arguments so it would be clear which arguments are optional.

```
    loadVanilla: async function(arg, parent = null, callback = null) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const res = await fetch(arg);
                
                if(!res.ok){
                    throw new Error(res.statusText);
                }

                const [hc, t] = (await res.text()).split('<script defer>');

                const s = document.createElement('script');
                s.textContent = t.split('</script>')[0];

                (parent ?? document.body).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', hc);

                s.onload = () => {
                    console.log('S LOADED')
                    resolve(`loaded good ${arg} \n `)
                    if (callback) callback()
                };
                s.onerror = reject;
                document.body.appendChild(s);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
    }
```